# How to copy files into a truecrypt partition in c#?

Tags: c#, truecrypt

I would like to copy files into an encrypted `truecrypt` partition using programming(c#) without mounting the partition.

`Is it possible?`

If so, may you give me an `example code` to do this!
Thank you!

Comment: ... and without asking the user for the password?

Comment: I can give it as a parameter, but I dont want that any dialog box to be shown.

Comment: maybe it's okay to mount the partition, just you want no GUI to be not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible? - yes.

easy enough to get an implementation for free? - probably not.

the TC source code is available, so the needed crypto stuff is there. you will probably want to port that to c# or build a dll that can be called by your c# prog.

additionally, since you are not mounting the container/partition, you will need a reader/writer for whatever filesystem is inside. FAT should be rather easy to do, but when it comes to NTFS, you maybe want to have a look at an open source NTFS driver ...